# pushing to live asp.net web application. Security Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

I would like help with the following asp.net error i now have after deploying my app to live

**Description**: *The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or **change the application's trust level in the configuration file***.

Most posts say to edit the web config file and allow trust. I read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493.aspx but am not really able to make sense of it.

If it helps to clarify things. I can connect to the database and retrieve results using LINQ.dbml DataContext. However when I try and assign the results to a Object, say for example.. The Data context is an external project compiled to a dll and put in the bin folder.

```
DataContext db = new DataContext("connectionstring");
var bankUser = (from u in db.Bankers
where u.banker_email == TXT_user.Text
&& u.banker_password == TXT_pass.Text
select u).Single();
```

it throws the error posted above.

I only have access via a control panel so any changes will have to be in web.config. I have set the project to have its own application pool.

any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I think you wonder why the exception was thrown so late. That's because LINQ is not executed until its first usage. That's called deferred execution.

http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai Kieran,
            In your web config,

Try this`<trust level="Full"/>` and we ll see what happens.... Just try it...

Source [Forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1192379.aspx)

Comment: @pandiya: Hey there. Thanks for the response. I have an configuration error with that put in the <system.web> I will look into how to fix this. On a side note what are the security implications when doing this.

Comment: @Kieren: Hai may be go through this it will give you a clear picture about trust level in a web application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493.aspx

Comment: a publicly exposed fully trusted application is a potential platform for hackers to launch attacks. The less an application is trusted, the more secure that application happens to be.

Comment: Got this sys admin to set it to full trust. It is now working no problems - Thanks Pandiya

Comment: Ok Let me know if any other issues you across with security and by the way u r always welcome....